# cannot build project with xcode 8 beta 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, carthage, xcode8-beta6

I am getting following error after I add a library via carthage -

> *library name* compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0)
>   than previous files (3.0) for architecture x86_64

I have tried it with Argo library. (https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo)

I have selected the correct xcode version using xcode-select utility.

What could be the problem? Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I learned, looks like you can't have libraries written in different versions of Swift.

In my Obj-C project I had 2 libs installed with CocoaPods
I updated the first one using the swift3 branch on github, and I converted the second one with Xcode.

Everything is building properly now!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as you've included another library (via cocoa pods or by linking the library directly etc...) which is compiled (or being compiled) in swift 2.

I've seen this a lot with Cocoapods (and Carthage)

Comment: I am using master branch of Argo (which they say is compatible with Swift 3.0) and using "swift3" branches of other projects. Still it doesn't work